# How to install libxml++ in Visual studio? Does nmake "see" vcpkg packages?

Tags: visual-studio, libxml2, nmake, vcpkg

I am having troubles installing libxmlplusplus (https://github.com/libxmlplusplus/libxmlplusplus) in Visual studio.

It is extremely annoying libxml2 wrapper that someone used to parse setup for project I am working and it has so many annoying little dependencies that I am tempted just to rewrite setup parsing with new code as I want to distribute this project as open source and I wish to no one to go through with installation of this library.

The README file in MSVC_NMake directory states that I only need to install libxml2 and include it in my VC directories.
Now I know that this hellish library also needs glib, and glibmm as few years back, this person http://hostagebrain.blogspot.com/2015/07/building-libxml-by-visual-studio.html went through horrible ways to build everything in VC when I am assuming glibmm and libxml2 were not easy to get.

I installed glibmm and libxml2 via vcpkg.
I downloaded libxmlplusplus, went to MSVC_NMake directory and run:

```
nmake /f Makefile.vc CFG=release
```

I am getting error messages as:

```
..\libxml++\attribute.cc: fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'msvc_recommended_pragmas.h': No such file or directory
```

So it seems some dependency is not linked, but have no idea which.
I checked ..\libxml++\attribute.cc and went down the include labyrinth to find out that it includes libxml\tree.h and libxml is part of libxml2, so I am suspecting libxml2 was not linked properly.

I exited powershell and then went to manually set VC includes and library dirs to vcpkg/packages/xxx location where they are installed, but I am still getting the same error.

I added glibmm to VC dirs, I even installed gtk and linked to VC hoping it'll find the missing header.

Can someone please help? Shouldn't vcpkg packages be in "path" when running nmake automatically? Am I missing completely different dependency?

Answer (score 0):

nmake won't magically see vcpkg installations. You need to either setup the environment variables (`LIB/LIBPATH/PATH/INCLUDE/CL/LINK` etc) for it or provide the paths to vcpkg in some other way.

That being said libxml++ is a available port in vcpkg -> see libxmlpp